# Filter elements from two lists

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, erlang-otp, concurrent-programming

Basically I have two lists something like

```
L1 = [one, two, three, five, eleven, million]
L2 = [five, million]
```

so I want to filter the elements from the second list L2

to get

```
[one, two, tree, eleven]
```

I have use the foldl function to loop the L1 and then a foreach loop to decide the element to append  comparing from the list 2 but i do not seem to get a logic right: I have something like this

```
56 filter_a(L1,L2) ->
 57    List = foldl(fun(X,A) ->
 58                 L = lists:foreach(fun(E) ->
 59                             case E =:= X of
 60                                 true ->
 61                                     [];
 62                                 _-> 
 63                                     X
 64                             end 
 65                     end, L2),
 66                 lists:append([A,[L]])
 67         end, [], L1),
 68    List.
```

How can i do this in an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
filter_a(L1,L2) ->
    [ X || X <- L1, lists:member(X,L2) =/= true ].
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just `L1 -- L2`? The complexity is the same O(N*M).